# error in setting java home environment variables ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu

i am new to ubuntu .initially i installed java in Ubuntu.
But i haven't set any envionment variables

After that installed maven build tool to build java package.when i compiled with build tool it shows some error says generic supports after 1.3 packages.

so i realize it JDK runs with 1.3. so i need set java environment variables for latest version

so in my Terminal java -version shows

```
beeshma@ubuntu:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

and i set java environment variables in through below steps
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/277806/how-to-set-java-home][1]

sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

Now go to end of file and add the following lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk/folder
#usually /usr/java/jdk or /usr/lib/java/jdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Now in terminal type:

sudo source ~/.bashrc

This will make it appear on every terminal if open.

Now you can cross check it by typing following line in terminal

```
$echo $PATH

/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45//bin:/home/beeshma/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45//bin
```

What my question when i execute mvn --help
 Fallowing error is coming

```
beeshma@ubuntu:~$ mvn -version
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
**We cannot execute /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45//bin/java**
```

Comment: You JAVA_HOME should not end with a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your export to:

export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Try if `/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45//bin/java` is indeed present.
- See if the `beeshma` user has the permissions to 'execute' java.
- Bonus: remove the trailing / in your `JAVA_HOME` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the JDK with the following command:

```
$sudo apt install default-jdk
```

The above command also sets the java environment variable automatically